# How is しかたない an opinion about a product feature?

Tags: translation

I have done my best to research the meaning of しかたない and I have discovered "It can't be helped", "It is unavoidable" and "Oh well".

These are all expressions of resignation in the face of inevitability, and I can't see when you would answer in that way when asked your opinion about a product feature.

Is there another interpretation that I haven't been able to find?

Here is a scan from the original document:

[image: it cant be helped as an opinion about a product feature]

Comment: I am not sure I understand your confusion. Why do you think しかたない is not a valid response to that question?

Comment: I can‘t think of any situation in which it would be appropriate. Q: „How would you feel if the product had the property X?“ A: „It‘s inevitable“

Comment: If your TV does not work properly anymore, is it really that strange that you say "oh well"?

Comment: Agreed. But this is a market research question by a manufacturer about a new (or even a planned) product.

Comment: ... or rather, about a planned product feature, as in „How would you feel if your car had an autopilot?“

Comment: @GrahamHorton I think you might be misunderstanding the question... 状態  is `the (current) state`,  not `the property`.

Comment: Understood. So in this case, what is the best translation? Perhaps "c'est la vie", i.e. "it's unfortunate, but there's nothing I can do about it."?

Comment: it must be somthing with japanese, it must be common to use しかたない in those situations. But I would never use it in my own language to describe what I'd feel in the situation though!

Comment: @FelipeOliveira It would be very helpful to me if that were true, i.e. it is a characteristically Japanese reaction that would not happen in the West. Do you have any idea how to find out?

Comment: As you already put forth 'C'e la vie' as a translation, I would suggest that that is a good way of looking at it. 'Troublesome, but not worth the stressing about or making the effort of doing anything about', as many things in 'la vie' can be.

Comment: To me, this doesn't seem like a question about a "product feature." It's about how people react to their TV getting old (or breaking), which is indirectly related to how likely they are to buy another TV.

Comment: It’s from a paper about product features, but it‘s not apparent from this fragment. It‘s actually a very bad example in context. A better example would be „How would you feel if your TV reacted to voice commands?“

Comment: @GrahamHorton: _"A better example would be „How would you feel if your TV reacted to voice commands?“"_ -- that example would not include しかたがない as an option for an answer.

Comment: As others say, unlike autopilot or voice commands, ものが二重にうつる (known as [ghosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosting_(television))) is not a product *feature* in the first place. This is asking "How much can you accept bad image quality of a TV". Just like new exciting features, bad points of the TV you already own can be a motivation to buy a new TV.

Comment: following what @naruto said, I believe translating しかたない to "I wouldn't care" would be more fitting? Q: "If your tv started showing problems how would you feel?" A: "I wouldn't care", "I would try and fix it", "I would buy a new one".

Answer (score 3):

もし、あなたのテレビの画像が状態が悪かったならば(二重に映るなど)、どうかんじますか = What do you feel if the TV doesn't display properly (e.g. Some ghost makes the double images)?

This is a survey. (Most of Japanese people say "Enquête" due to the French word of this introduced before English.) You can select your answer from the options:

1. 気に入る Still like it.
2. 当然である It has to be a matter of course.
3. 何も感じない   Feel nothing.
4. しかたない Have no choice.
5. 気に入らない Don't like it.
6. その他(...) Other (...)

The electrician or the radio station engineer and the same kind of the tech savvy fellows would choose, しかたない by the reasons such as the house is in the forest, skyscraper or far away from the station.

*When we have an ordinary television (non-digital), sometimes it wasn't clear by a slight delay of radio wave echos from mountain/building reflections.*

Comment: I think your answer is helpful. I don't understand the downvotes. Your English isn't perfect, but it is understandable.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't really understand the last part. People who are tech savvy would say しかたない because of something related to the location of their house? I'm trying to figure out what that their house location would have to do with it.

Comment: @psw1747 回答を改善するために、他のユーザーさんたちが指摘コメントすることはよくありますし、そのためのコメント欄でもあります。善意によるものとご理解いただき、攻撃的な応答はお避けください。[Be Nice Policy](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/conduct) もご参照ください。

Comment: @Leebo I think what he's saying is that if you understand how TVs work and you see ghosting because you're in an area with bad reception, you'll say "Oh well! It can't be helped". Whereas, if you don't understand that the problem is due to bad reception, you'll get angry and complain to the TV manufacturer.

Comment: Ah, okay... Non-digital signal TVs, haha, didn't even consider that.

Comment: @Chocolate, I did take the word choices and grammar errors as a suggestion and good ones, but it came with -2 down votes then I thought just I was useless. I am an old man and I do not accept "@。。。。。" post as polite ones. You should remember people  are here for unpaid work, volunteering.

Comment: @Leebo, Good grip, yes, that's not a long time ago. VHF and UHF short radio waves (or ultra-high freq.) reaches just for 100 km or less. And the mountains or buildings makes them double images or least unclear, only the audio goes through. When we migrated to digital TV, still the trailers, mini bike and aeroplane goes/flies by my house, the broadcasting interrupts.

Comment: I don't think I have ever met someone in my life who doesn't have cable TV (at the very least, I've never visited a house that didn't), so yeah, it wasn't clicking. That's just my blind spot.

Comment: psw1747 (deleted) aka user20428 (deleted). If you happen to visit this page again:  I'll admit I wasn't being polite. After a couple people suggested corrections you overreacted and threatened to 'take your ball and go home'. I simply informed you that that was your prerogative. My comment might have lacked some tact and the deference you felt you deserve, but I don't tailor my comments to the potential age of the other party and the comment wasn't meant to be mean. Incidentally, we are all volunteers, ...

Comment: Well, I would expect regular people to say 仕方ない in such case, but not an engineer. Wouldn't an engineer come up with a technical solution for the problem? That's precisely their job, they solve problems.