# Is しかたない a characteristically Japanese response to a question?

Tags: culture

It has been suggested in a comment here: [How is しかたない an opinion about a product feature?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65544/how-is-%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-an-opinion-about-a-product-feature) 
that しかたない might be a characteristically Japanese response to a question (that a Western person might never give).

Is this a valid observation? If so, what would a Japanese person mean when replying in this manner to a market research question about a product?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your other post, I think that it's not a peculiarly Japanese response. I would think of it in that context as an expression of the feeling *"there's nothing I can do about it"*.

However, I also think that in Japanese culture, it's more common than in English-speaking culture to express feelings of "there's nothing I/we/you/anyone can do about it".

In English-speaking culture *(please let me know if you agree)*, a person who often expresses such feelings of some kind of "helplessness" is likely to be looked down upon as not being motivated, self-empowered, etc. It seems to me, in Japanese culture this is not the case and expressions like this are more likely to elicit understanding, fellow-feeling and respect for a persons humility.

Comment: The Wikipedia article certainly corroborates your interpretation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shikata_ga_nai